# SPWeb.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.TimeZone is null

Tags: sharepoint-2013, user-profile

I have a code

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPTimeZone tz = web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
```

It works fine for 350 users. Only 2 show error on the second line:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object
All our users have their Time zone set in Profile service. the same as the 2 that error.
Anyone has an idea why it is?
Thank you

Comment: Turns out the SPWeb web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings is null so that is why there is no time zone. Is there a PowerShell to create it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run the "**User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint language and region synchronization**" time job again and then check if it works.

And we can use the REST API below to check the profile properties of the 2 users , and check if "**SPS-TimeZone**" is null.

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\user'
```

To avoid the issue in the code, I suggest you use the code below.

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPTimeZone tz;
if (web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings != null)
{
    tz = web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
}
else if (web.RegionalSettings != null)
{
    tz = web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
}
else
{
    tz = SPRegionalSettings.GlobalTimeZones[web.Site.WebApplication.DefaultTimeZone];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: I tried it against 2 2013 farms http://ecgpulse/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='ECGmc\ogal' but got back:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Unknown Error</m:message>
</m:error>

Comment: Did you run the User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint language and region synchronization time job? And try to restart the SharePoint Timer service.

Comment: Made sure it is working and the job history shows success:User Profile Service (ECGmc) - System Job to Manage User Profile Synchronization  SP-AZ-Test-app   0:00:00 Succeeded 2/7/2020 6:58 AM but I still get "500 Internal Server Error" on the _api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor

Comment: Further logging showed that the containing object is null. SPWeb web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings is null. Is there a powershell way to create it?